# Write a function header for a call with &argument

Tags: c++

I have the following code.

```
int quotient, remainder, numerator, denominator;
numerator = 128;
denominator = 5;
divide(numerator, denominator, &quotient, &remainder);
```

and I want to ask what does it mean to have argument with "&". and how can I write "divide" function header?

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the "address-of" operator and creates a pointer to the variable. The function header for `divide` should be

```
void divide(int num, int denom, int* quot, int* rem);
```

Comment: But, "quot" and "rem" are not declared as pointers. So, how can I declare them as pointers in the function header ?

Comment: @Ghadeer `quot` and `rem` *are* declared as pointers in the function header I gave. The `*` indicates they are both pointers. Also, in case there is any confusion, note that these are *not* the same variables as `quotient` and `remainder` in the code *you* gave. For one thing, the names are different. For another thing, they are in two different functions.

Comment: In my question, "&quotient" and "&remainder" in the function call are the variables that are declared as "int"

Comment: @Ghadeer `quotient` is an `int`. `&quotient` is the address of that `int`, i.e. a pointer.

Comment: but, "&quotient" is not declared in the code, so how I can use a variable without declaring it?

Comment: `&quotient` isn't a *variable*. It's an *expression* with an operator (`&`) and a variable (`quotient`). When you call the `divide` function, the value of the expression `&quotient` will be stored in the variable `quot` which is declared in the function header.